# Drag and drop support when subclassing from QAbstractItemModel

Tags: c++, qt, model, drag-and-drop, qabstractitemmodel

I subclassed from `QAbstractItemModel`, put model into `QTreeView`, everything is fine.

Now I want to support drag and drop, so it will be possible change item position with mouse.
I set to `QTreeView` `dragDrop` mode to `DragDrop`, `defDropAction` `MoveAction`, `drag` enabled to true. I can drag item, it appears near mouse, but on putting nothing happens.

What methods from `QAbstractItemModel` I need to realize that my model will support drag and drop?

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement [QAbstractItemModel::supportedDropActions()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#supportedDropActions) and [QAbstractItemModel::supportedDragActions()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#supportedDragActions). The [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html#using-drag-and-drop-with-item-views) explain it pretty well, too.

The poster at this link has some sample code: http://forum.qt.io/topic/9417/solved-supporteddropactions-in-qabstractitemmodel